# download Facebook video (with no user access token)

Tags: objective-c, facebook-graph-api

trying get Facebook video data (video url, thumbnail, desc etc...)

Facebook return error for "access token"

- The video is public

  ```
  url_str = @"https://www.facebook.com/DonaldTrump/videos/vb.153080620724/10159664271045725/?type=2&theater";




  FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                initWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url_str]
                                parameters:@{@"fields": @"id, source,picture"}
                                HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
  [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                        NSDictionary* result,
                                        NSError *error) {


      if(result){

      }
      else{

      }



  }];
  ```

error message:

```
   body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 104;
            "fbtrace_id" = G2cJAV2mSlS;
            message = "An access token is required to request this resource.";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 400;
```

Comment: well, DID you use an access token? the error message is very clear that you need one.

Comment: All API calls (besides the redirects for profile pictures) need an access token. If the content is publicly available and from a page (not a user profile), you can use your app access token. Otherwise, you will either need a user access token from a user that can see the content, or a page access token for that page.

Comment: @CBroe, ok got the idea √ so, I created a New App on Facebook Developers Consol, got an App ID, but how can I use my app token in the SDK Paragraph?

Comment: Dunno, consult the documentation of whatever library/SDK you are using there ...